# How to print object of arrays in table format through angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

This is my object containing some arrays

```
$scope.listInfo = {
            id : [2,3],
            officerName : ["Bob",'Alex'],
            userInfoId : [3,5],
            status: ["asd","asd"]
       };
```

this is my html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Officer Name</th>
                <th>User General Info Id</th>
                <th>Status Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="option in listInfo.id">
                <td>{{option}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

here i can only Print the Ids But i want print the whole objects What should i do?

Comment: Use a correct model ? If you want to print an array of objects, then you should have an array of objects, not an object made of arrays ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're stuck with that object structure, you could do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="option in listInfo.id">
    <td>{{option}}</td>
    <td>{{listInfo.officerName[$index]}}</td>
    <td>{{listInfo.userInfoId[$index]}}</td>
    <td>{{listInfo.status[$index]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here, `$index` is the index in the `listInfo.id` array which means that in order for this to work, the other arrays have to be at least the same size as `listInfo.id`

My suggestion will be to restructure the data to make it easier to access.

Comment: Are you sure all index are correct with reference of id

Comment: @Devrajverma Yes, all arrays in the example object have the same length, I should probably mention that in order for this to work, all arrays have to be the same size

Comment: But if any data is missing then it will generate parsing error.

Comment: in my case all index are corret with reference id. Thanks it worked :)

Comment: Yes i can understand but this types solution marked as jugad it will defiantly fatega in future. So i suggest use proper solution @Titus already mentioned in his answer so go with valid structure for ask you back end developer return proper array.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are using is in the form of object with arrays.... But to obtain the solution your data need to be in the form of array of objects.

```
$scope.listInfo = [
   {
       id: '2',
       officerName: 'Bob',
       userInfoId: '3',
       status: 'asd'
    }, {
       id: '3',
       officerName: 'Alex',
       userInfoId: '5',
       status: 'asd'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your case your array structure is not valid firstly create valid array then you can print whole kindly check below valid structure.

```
$scope.listInfo = [
    {id:2,officerName:'Bob',userInfoId:3,status:'asd'},
    {id:3,officerName:'Alex',userInfoId:5,status:'asd'},

];
```

And show like below :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Officer Name</th>
                <th>User General Info Id</th>
                <th>Status Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="option in listInfo">
                <td>{{option.id}}</td>
                <td>{{option.officerName}}</td>
                <td>{{option.userInfoId}}</td>
                <td>{{option.status}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```